# facebook FB.ui pre define default message?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

Can we set custom pre define default message in facebook send FB.ui function?

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'send',
        message: 'Facebook Friend Invitation',
        picture: 'imageurl',
        title: "Invite your friends to",
        link: 'Link',
        description: 'text',
});
```

> Please find attached screenshort.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible and not allowed according to the platform policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

> Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message
>   parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the
>   person can edit or remove the content before sharing.